# Lost power while upgrading to 12.04, how do I fix the botched install?

Tags: upgrade, 12.04, power-management

I was upgrading from 11.10 to 12.04 just for kicks and lost power to the PC while it was about 3/4 done with the install section of the upgrade.

I can login successfully and launch apps from the terminal (posting this from the comp). The main thing I'm missing is the launcher dock and the notification bar at the top.

Since I am able to easily access the terminal, I've tried `apt-get dist-upgrade`, `apt-get upgrade`, and `dpkg --configure -a`. All of which do nothing.

Is there anything I can do to fix the install aside from downloading the ISO and going off that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seemed to have fixed my problem, everything was installed fine it was just unity needed to be reset. I think it may have been an issue with compiz.

Just needed to reset unity using `unity --reset` and problem solved.